# Updating a PostgreSQL array field in SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Consider the following taggable model:

```
from sqlalchemy import cast, Text
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY, array


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    tags = Column(ARRAY(Text), nullable=False,
                  default=cast(array([], type_=Text), ARRAY(Text)))
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to update the field. Of course I can do something as suggested in [Update a PostgreSQL array using SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219775/update-a-postgresql-array-using-sqlalchemy) :

```
user = session.query(User).get(1)
user.tags = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
session.add(user)
session.commit()
```

But that solution assumes setting the entire array value.

What if I just want to append a value to the array? What if I want to bulk tag a group of `User` objects in one query? How do I do that?

Comment: To the former, https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html. Note that `session.add(user)` is redundant. `user` is already in `session` after fetch, and is not transient to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You may use SQLAlchemy [text](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) and PostgreSQL [array_append](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html) functions:

`text('array_append(tags, :tag)')`

For `smallint` type you may use PostgreSQL and [SQLAlchemy type castings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064007/how-to-explicitly-cast-type-of-array-literal-in-sqlalchemy-using-postgresql):

`text('array_append(tags, :tag\:\:smallint)')`

`TestTable.tags.contains(cast((1,), TestTable.tags.type))`

Examples:

---

Appending a value to an integer PostgreSQL array:

```
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, update, text
    from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

    Base = declarative_base()

    class TestTable(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'test_table'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        tags = Column(ARRAY(Integer), nullable=False)

    engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres')
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)

    DBSession.bulk_insert_mappings(
        TestTable,
        ({'id': i, 'tags': [i // 4]} for i in range(1, 11))
    )

    DBSession.execute(
        update(
            TestTable
        ).where(
            TestTable.tags.contains((1,))
        ).values(tags=text(f'array_append({TestTable.tags.name}, :tag)')),
        {'tag': 100}
    )

    DBSession.commit()
```

Appending a value to a small integer PostgreSQL array:

```
    from sqlalchemy import SmallInteger, cast

    class TestTable(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'test_table2'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        tags = Column(ARRAY(SmallInteger), nullable=False)

    DBSession.execute(
        update(
            TestTable
        ).where(
            TestTable.tags.contains(cast((1,), TestTable.tags.type))
        ).values(tags=text(f'array_append({TestTable.tags.name}, :tag\:\:smallint)')),
        {'tag': 100}
    )
```

Result:

```
id |  tags   
----+---------
  1 | {0}
  2 | {0}
  3 | {0}
  8 | {2}
  9 | {2}
 10 | {2}
  4 | {1,100}
  5 | {1,100}
  6 | {1,100}
  7 | {1,100}
```